# Nexth Auth Logging me out on every refresh despite having given a session the time i logged in

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

Hi im relatively new to next-auth with mongodb coming from a java background. I have a simple app that has a the index.tsx page secured and a login page to authenticate a user. The app is a severless NextJS app with Mongodd database connected. The login page is pretty simple so i'll leave the input styles and fields and focus on the functions instead.

for context, these are the functions in my `authmiddleware.ts` file
**authmiddleware.ts**

```
export function isLoggedInMiddleware(ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext & { req: { session?: Session | null } }) {
  const { session } = ctx.req || {};
  if (!session || !session.user) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/login" });
    ctx.res.end();
    return;
  }
}

export function isLoggedOutMiddleware(ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext & { req: { session?: Session | null } }) {
      const { session } = ctx.req || {};
      if (session) {
        ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: "/" });
        ctx.res.end();
        return;
      }
    }
```

My simple login

**Login.tsx**

```
const LoginPage = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState(false)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const router = useRouter()

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    setLoading(true)
    setLoginError(false)
    try {
      console.log("button clicked")
      // const loginRes = await loginUser({ username, password });
      const response = await signIn("credentials", {
        redirect: false,
        username,
        password
      })
      if (response && !response.ok) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setLoginError(true);
          setLoading(false);
        }, 2000)

      }
      else {
        console.log("response")
        setTimeout(() => {
          router.push("/")
        }, 2000)

      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  };
  return (<>...Login html elements<>)

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async (ctx) => {
  isLoggedOutMiddleware(ctx);
  return {
    props: {},
  };
};


export default LoginPage;
```

so when i submit my credentials everything works fine, I get logged in if they are correct or the i get a 401 if they are incorrect. logging the session prints out the correct details. However immediately after i reload the page i get logged out.

This is what my [...nextauth].ts file looks like

**[...nextauth].ts**

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { db } from "../../../../helpers/api"
import { compare } from "bcrypt"
import { IEmployee } from "../../../../types"

const options: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "credentials",
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "password", type: "password" }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {

        const user = await db.Employee.findOne({
          username: credentials?.username
        }).select("+password")

        if (!user) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials")
        }

        console.log("attempting authentication")
        const isPasswordCorrect = await compare(credentials!.password, user.password);

        if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }

        const userWithoutPassword = {
          name: user?.name,
          username: user?.username,
          role: user?.role
        }

        return userWithoutPassword;
      }
    })
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 5 * 60 * 60,

  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      user && (token.user = user)
      return token
    },
    // jwt: true,
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      const user = token.user as IEmployee;
      session.user = user;
      return session
    }
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
}

export default NextAuth(options)
```

and this is what my secured index.tsx file looks like

**index.tsx**

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const { currentView, setCurrentView } = useAppContext();

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Container h="90vh">
        <ReceiptList />
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async (ctx) => {
  isLoggedInMiddleware(ctx);
  return {
    props: {},
  };
};

export default Home;
```

and **_app.tsx**

```
`function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <AppProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />

      </AppProvider>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;`
```

Ive seen some references talk about the Credentials Provider not being able to store database sessions and this case im using mongodb.